# Best way to add space between columns with alternating colored rows

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I did some search on the topic without success. Most of the time people want to **remove** [spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186650/overhang-parameter-of-rowcolor-changes-overhang-of-each-cell-not-just-the-row), or have problems with [last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262375/rowcolors-when-space-is-removed-with), etc.
In my case I want the spaces to be there and between columns.

I have manage to do so using a [colored rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146014/modify-font-color-in-a-tabular-structure) but that doesn't look good (the code I mean) and feels like kind of a workaround.

The main issue here is that my table will be printed and filled by hand, so the vertical separation must be clear and even/odd coloring is necessary to avoid confusion.

**Edit**: As stated by `Zarko` my question was not clear enough, so I'm rephrasing.

**Is there a best/more elegant way of adding space between columns with alternating colored rows?**

I've used `rowcolors` for alternating color (SpringGreen/gray) rows but other solutions might be suitable too. The space between rows isn't much important to me, as the coloring does define were each rows starts/ends.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt}
\begin{table}[ht]
\rowcolors{3}{SpringGreen}{gray!20!white}
{\large 
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}C{2cm}|L{2cm}|L{2cm}|L{2cm}|L{2cm}|L{2cm}|L{2cm}<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}
\arrayrulecolor{black} 
\toprule
Part &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Calibration date}} \\
Number & \multicolumn{5}{c}{}   \\
\midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\arrayrulecolor{black} 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is probably to simply insert some space between the columns:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}!{\hspace{3pt}}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}!{\hspace{3pt}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\rowcolors[]{3}{SpringGreen}{gray!20!white}

\begin{tabular}{C{2cm}L{2cm}L{2cm}L{2cm}L{2cm}L{2cm}L{2cm}}
\toprule
Part &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Calibration date}} \\
Number & \multicolumn{5}{c}{}   \\
\midrule
adk\hfill blbl &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that's really simple! However i'm struggling to remove that tiny extra space after the last column without defining a new columntype.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

To code is added `makecell` package for use of macro `\thead{...}` in column headings. Coloring of cells is moved to definition of new column type `C`, all rules has standard width and color. With this I estimate that code is more concise and simple:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\large}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{white}\columncolor{gray!30}[.5\tabcolsep]%
                    \centering\arraybackslash}p{20mm}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\thead{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{$\;$} *{7}{C} @{\rule{0pt}{5ex}$\;$} }
    \toprule
\mc{1}{Part\\ Number} &  \mc{6}{Calibration date} \\
    \midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace[8pt]% if you like bigger vertical space
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Instead two alternating rows' color see if increasing vertical space at each second second row. In this case the table looks as follows:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\large}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{white}\columncolor{gray!30}[.5\tabcolsep]%
                    \centering\arraybackslash}p{20mm}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\thead{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{$\;$} C @{\qquad} *{6}{C} @{\rule{0pt}{5ex}$\;$} }
    \toprule
\mc{1}{Part\\ Number} &  \mc{6}{Calibration date} \\
    \midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace[12pt]
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace[12pt]
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace[12pt]
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\   \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually need even/odd coloring, thats why I used `rowcolor`S and not `rowcolor`. Your approach is interesting.

Comment: This is not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Edited. Even/odd coloring is necessary.

Comment: Well, than my answer is not of big help for you. Even your MWE haven't two color rows (white is not visible) ... as solution, you need to change rows' colors from white to something else. Considering my MWE maybe is solution to add `midrule` each second row or each second row increase vertical space between rows.